# Shut down/release log + log4rs logger so it can be reconfigured in a new PyO3 call?

Tags: logging, rust, configuration, pyo3

I am using crates `log` and `log4rs`.

I'm trying to have a situation where my Python code (I'm using PyO3) can call the Rust Python-enabled function involved a second time, to re-run things.

I have a file logging.rs in the same directory as lib.rs which configures logging. Rust panics the second time Python calls the Rust `configure_logging` function, probably because some resource used in logging is unreleased. One of the 2 `Appender`s logs to a file, in fact does rolling logging ([RollingFileAppender](https://docs.rs/log4rs/latest/log4rs/append/rolling_file/struct.RollingFileAppender.html)). This may be relevant.

I spotted that `RollingFileAppender` has a method `flush`. This might (but probably doesn't) do enough to shut things down. To set up the log4rs logger initially I do this, having built the config object:

```
log4rs::init_config(config)?;
```

I tried calling `flush` on the `logger()` object at the end of the first Rust run of the function. No change. I also tried getting the back trace, but this doesn't seem to show which line in the logging.rs file causes the problem:

```
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library\std\src\panicking.rs:578
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library\core\src\panicking.rs:67
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library\core\src\result.rs:1687
   3: populate_index::my_extension
   4: std::panicking::try
   5: populate_index::my_extension
    ...
```

Maybe the information is reduced there because I'm running this as a PyO3 module?

I'm even open to the idea that maybe the logging, once configured, will persist after my first PyO3 call has ended? And therefore, at the second call, I should just not configure, and somehow try and piggyback on to the previously set-up configuration. This seems unlikely because I have not made any provision for logging to run in its own thread or process.

**Confirmation:**
So having run this PyO3 module once, but not having terminated the Python app, I went to examine the current log file. I was able to open it but not to edit it: "Sharing violation". This appears to show that after leaving the PyO3 module the thread involved had not let go of the file. And yet I presume that `lib4rs` (or `log`) involve some mechanism to release resources like files at termination if just running a normal Rust module...?

**Something I tried**

```
pub fn shut_down_logging(){
    drop(logger());
}
```

... called just before exiting the Rust Python-callable function. Doesn't work.

Comment: `log4js::init_config()` undoubtedly calls [`log::set_logger`](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/fn.set_logger.html) which says *"This function may only be called once in the lifetime of a program."* So yes, you should avoid reconfiguring the logger on subsequent calls.

Comment: Yes I had seen that. And that makes sense in a non-PyO3 context. My question is specific to the PyO3 context. The fact that something is still hanging on to the file handle (or whatever) suggests to me that this thread is not being permitted to die. But how could the logger set up still be accessible on the second Rust module call?

Comment: `static` variables are allocated when the Rust library gets *loaded* into your Python program and aren't recreated on each call. They persist until the whole program ends (or perhaps if you get Python to *unload* the Rust library but I have no clue how to go about that).

Comment: Ah, useful-to-know technical info that. I presume a log/log4rs setup must involve one or more static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing!!!

I changed as follows:

```
// logging::configure_logging().expect("logging configure problem");
match logging::configure_logging() {
    Ok(()) => (),
    Err(e) => {
        println!("error was {e}");
    }
}
info!("Starting...");
```

... the second call to this module **finds the existing log setup** and "Starting..." is logged! NB the error message being "attempted to set a logger after the logging system was already initialized".